# In Apache log file, why do I see \xef\xbf\?

Tags: apache-2.2

In Apache error log, I see many requests like this one. It seems that the requests are coming from China.

File does not exist: C:/site/htdocs/analysis\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd, referer: http://wo.iuni.com.cn/card/?p=zfau2mj48AVTKFeWO8mnePcdq7zl+q4+tPCaeoKR2reaA9jgJO0XdeO/EjyUl2rPl2Nye8qPK2kkuuwEO6GS4WxUvSp39KwXlY+zt64GNVUTUo8p1Z0HTPbk/NjFDYSDff3pIfHIIKRSQIvX/TTvl/g4IQLoLV4kpC0tIsuX/y1x9xec0L39H+v1VIYa7etp

How can I translate \xef\xbf... to understand why did it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd` is probably Unicode. Also, the hex-String `\xef\xbf\xbd` translates to the black diamond with the question mark in it (Apparently called the "REPLACEMENT CHARACTER"). Three times.
This string ist also specifically mentioned in the document [UTF-8 decoder capability and stress test](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-test.txt).

My best guess is that someone either made a mistake or tries to put bad data into a script; however, if the latter would be true, she forgot to set at `?` between the path and the `\xef\xbf\xbd` string.

Answer (score 0):

These are the special characters that cannot be displayed like natural alphabet symbols, numbers for example like SPACE or NEWLINE. Each \xef is a hexadecimal representation of a symbol with number EF of ASCII table (full table here http://www.ascii-code.com/ and more examples can be found).

These codes appear in logs if your server is scanned or if user entered wrong url containing special characters.